# Recovering an RAID6 using ddrescue. mdadm: failed to add, invalid argument

Tags: linux, mdadm, data-recovery, raid6

I had 3 drives fail in a matter of a week on a RAID6.  Luckily, one drive seemed to be mostly fine.  I was able to run ddrescue and it copied all but one small area (couldn't read 14MB out of 3TB).

However, when trying to assemble the array using the cloned drive (after removing the original), I receive some issues (**sdm** being the cloned drive):

```
# mdadm --assemble --scan --force /dev/md127
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdm1 to /dev/md127: Invalid argument
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md127: Input/output error
```

Examining the drive shows fine:

```
# mdadm -E /dev/sdm1
/dev/sdm1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 9112a098:66dde535:f258911c:3af7e312
           Name : cstor2.localdomain:127  (local to host cstor2.localdomain)
  Creation Time : Wed Aug 27 01:34:29 2014
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 12

 Avail Dev Size : 5859110912 (2793.84 GiB 2999.86 GB)
     Array Size : 29295549440 (27938.41 GiB 29998.64 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5859109888 (2793.84 GiB 2999.86 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=18446744073701229568 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 4d8e7a74:f9dca0be:0d899e70:cc798c51

    Update Time : Sat Jan  2 21:15:23 2016
       Checksum : dc798583 - correct
         Events : 9341937

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA.A.AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

This matches what the other drive was reporting.  However, it throws the invalid argument any time I try to assemble the original RAID6.  Does anyone have any ideas on the invalid  argument error or how I can work around this.

I was pondering whether I should recreate the array with assume-clean but I'm not sure if that would work correctly with 10 of 12 drives.

Comment: Can you please show the results of grep _MD_ /boot/config-`uname -r` to see your kernel configuration regarding RAID.
Are you booting from some kind of recovery CD/USB? Then please post the results of mdadm -E /dev/sd(X)1 for all devices involved "after=18446744073701229568 sectors" does not look normal.